# Prevent an activity being destroyed on low memory

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activites in my application. Activity A has a list view and on clicking an item in listview Activity B is loaded. Upon clicking back button it'll go to Activity A and displays listview properly in some devices. But in some devices with low memory the Acivity A wont load listview on clicking back button in Activity B.(instead Activity A will be blank).

How do i overcome this challenge?

Comment: No why would that be a good idea.....

Comment: You should always expect that your activities can be destroyed if they're not visible. Retain your state in the appropriate callbacks.

Comment: It is possible (and makes perfect sense) to prevent Activity from being destroyed due to memory shortage. It is not possible to prevent it's destruction due to other reasons (such as the application becoming inactive and reaching the end of OOM destruction list), but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @rbhagwat
Destruction of activity due to low memory is a good thing, .. since you havent provided any code, so i can suggest you to populate your list with only few items, may 2, 3 .. and check for its flow, .. if its still giving the issue, than there is problem with your code, in that case i would suggest you to read how to make Custom ListView
here is a good startup
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done.
Android can destroy any activity upon certain situations. All you can do is retain the data (for example underlying dataset of your adapter) in onSaveInstanceState()  and restore it in onCreate()  or onRestoreInstanceState().